# Django validators - selected check boxes

Tags: python, django

Here is my form in django:

```
class CarPurchase(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Car name")
    brand = forms.CharField(label="Brand")
    color = forms.DateField(label="Color")
    payment_possibilities = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
```

The `payment_possibilities` is a group of checkboxes where user can choose the ways he is open to pay with. I want him to choose at least one option here, but he can also choose more of them. I want to validate this by django validators.

Is there any way I can tell django to get the number of selected checkboxes? I was already thinking about this implementation:

```
    payment_possibilities = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        validators=[validate_payment]
    )


def validate_payment(value):
    ...
```

but this for the first didn't seem to be the right approach and I also left unsure about how to access that number of check boxes selected.